# Removing untracked files from git

Tags: git

I'm not quite sure how I've ended up in this state but for some reason git is detecting everything under my c:\Users directory as being untracked files so when I do a git status I get the following:

```
>git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../../../3D Objects/
    ../../../AppData/
    ../../../Contacts/
    ../../../Desktop/
    ../../../Documents/
    ../../../Downloads/
    ../../../Favorites/
    ../../../Google Drive/
    ../../../Links/
    ../../../Music/
    ..... and many more
```

Obviously I don't want these to be tracked or committed.  How can I remove these from being tracked in git **without deleting any files from my file system**

Comment: Just create a `.gitignore` file - see here https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Did you accidentally create a new Git repository, or cloned one into a very top-level directory, or moved a `.git` directory around manually?

Comment: Ah, judging by `no commits yet`, it seems you've somehow created a new Git repository which you apparently didn't mean to.

Comment: @mkrieger.  Yeah that's what seems to have happened!

Comment: @mkrieger.  Yes, that was the one thanks!  I obviously must have ran git init against my c:\users at some point and not realised.